# Generate a tree of structs with testing/quick, respecting invariants

Tags: testing, go

I have a tree of structs which I'd like to test using `testing/quick`, but constraining it to within my invariants.

This example code works:

```
var rnd = rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))
type X struct {
    HasChildren bool
    Children    []*X
}
func TestSomething(t *testing.T) {
    x, _ := quick.Value(reflect.TypeOf(X{}), rnd)
    _ = x
    // test some stuff here
}
```

But we hold `HasChildren = true` whenever `len(Children) > 0` as an invariant, so it'd be better to ensure that whatever `quick.Value()` generates respects that (rather than finding "bugs" that don't actually exist).

I figured I could define a Generate function which uses `quick.Value()` to populate all the variable members:

```
func (X) Generate(rand *rand.Rand, size int) reflect.Value {
    x := X{}

    throwaway, _ := quick.Value(reflect.TypeOf([]*X{}), rand)
    x.Children = throwaway.Interface().([]*X)

    if len(x.Children) > 0 {
        x.HasChildren = true
    } else {
        x.HasChildren = false
    }

    return reflect.ValueOf(x)
}
```

But this is panicking:

> panic: value method main.X.Generate called using nil *X pointer [recovered]

And when I change Children from `[]*X` to `[]X`, it dies with a stack overflow.

The documentation is very thin on examples, and I'm finding almost nothing in web searches either.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the `testing/quick` source code it seems that you can't create recursive custom generators and **at the same time** reuse the `quick` library facilities to generate the array part of the struct, because the `size` parameter, that is designed to limit the number of recursive calls, cannot be passed back into `quick.Value(...)`

https://golang.org/src/testing/quick/quick.go (see around line 50)

in your case this lead to an infinite tree that quickly "explodes" with 1..50 leafs at each level (that's the reason for the stack overflow).

If the function `quick.sizedValue()` had been public we could have used it to accomplish your task, but unfortunately this is not the case.

BTW since HasChildren is an invariant, can't you simply make it a struct method?

```
type X struct {
    Children    []*X
}

func (me *X) HasChildren() bool {
    return len(me.Children) > 0
}

func main() {
    .... generate X ....
    if x.HasChildren() {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into this! And yes, `HasChildren` from the contrived example can definitely be a struct method : )